# XSD (xml schema) that validate an integer with comma delimited (by 1000th)

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have something like 1,000,212 or 23,356 or just 235

You got the idea.

I can't seem to find a datatype/restriction in XSD rule that allow me to do that.  I assume I have to use patttern reg matching string?  If so, how should I write this?

I have something like this.  But it doens't seem to work

```
  <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
    <xs:pattern value="[1-9][0-9]*(, ?[1-9][0-9]*)*"/>
  </xs:restriction>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you show what you have tried, Stack Overflow readers will assume you are working to solve the problem and will try to help you understand what's going wrong.  If you don't, many readers will assume (rightly or wrongly) that you just want someone else to do your work for you; you'll get a lot less help that way.  So:  what have you tried?

Comment: edited.  I tried the codes above

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression matches any sequence of digits not beginning with zero, and containing arbitrary numbers of commas optionally followed by blanks and separated by at least one digit (the first of which cannot be zero).  So it should accept all of your examples.  I'm guessing that what is wrong is that it also accepts examples like `1234567890` and `1,23,45678,9`, and rejects `10,000`.

If you want commas to appear in the conventional pattern, you will need to formulate a regular expression that requires commas to be separated by exactly three digits, and allow no more three digits before the first comma.

I'd try `[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(, ?[0-9]{3})*` and see whether it does what you need.